# Using an image as a background of a section on a website

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use an image as a background of a section on my website but i can't fill the section with it.
It Should look like this:
[image]

instead all i got is this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<header>
    <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="logo-header">
        <img class="logo-lorem" src="./imagens/Grupo 105.png" alt="">   
    </div>
        <nav class="links-header">
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>      
        </nav>
        
        <button>Lorem ipsum</button>
</header>
<div class="hero-img-container">
    <div class="hero-text-container">
        <p class="p-topo">Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p class="p-meio">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        <button class="btn-hero">Lorem ipsum</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hero-img-container{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;

background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-image: url(./imagens/ballpen-blur-close-up-461077.png);
```

}

Comment: please post your code as text, we can't copy/paste text from images! :)

Comment: Agreed regarding the above comment and also include your HTML as well not just CSS.

Comment: Ok the code is there

Answer (score 0):

As you have the css rule "background-size:cover", it means the background image covers the entire element (.hero-img-container).

So this also means the ".hero-img-container" element is not the right place to attach the background image.

It should be attached to a parent of .hero-img-container. At least a parent that has the desired dimensions. Difficult to say which parent tag with the code you posted.

Comment: so how can i make an image be the background of a section of the page ?

Comment: Above and below your image you have large blank spaces, these blank spaces show that .hero-img-container element is not covering the area you want. Is there a parent that covers all that area ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the object-fit propriety

object-fit: cover;

You can check out more info down below
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp